# Anaconda + Apache + mod_wsgi + Ubuntu

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, anaconda, mod-wsgi

I'm running a server with Ubuntu and Apache. Now I'm trying to get Anaconda working with mod_wsgi but just can't get it to work.

First off. It is working if I use mod_wsgi-express. By following the instruction at https://anaconda.org/pypi/mod_wsgi in section Installing into Python I can get it working by first setting `PYTHONHOME=/opt/anaconda` and then `/opt/anaconda3/bin/mod_wsgi-express start-server`.

I want to use Apache so I load the mod_wsgi module from anaconda into apache. And then I have a VirtualHost looking like this:

```
WSGIPythonHome /opt/anaconda3
WSGIPythonPath /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/path/to/application
<VirtualHost *:8080>
ServerName example.com
WSGIDaemonProcess example python-home=/opt/anaconda3 python-path=path/to/application:/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup example

WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/application/wsgi.py

<Directory /path/to/application/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/application>
<Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Now to the problem. I get this error in my apache error log. I get the same error if I don't specify `PYTHONHOME=/opt/anaconda` with mod_wsgi_express.

```
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.159233 2017] [core:trace4] [pid 16941] mpm_common.c(530): mpm child 19356 (gen 0/slot 1) started
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.159638 2017] [core:trace4] [pid 16941] mpm_common.c(530): mpm child 19357 (gen 0/slot 2) started
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.160049 2017] [core:trace4] [pid 16941] mpm_common.c(530): mpm child 19358 (gen 0/slot 6) started
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.160467 2017] [core:trace4] [pid 16941] mpm_common.c(530): mpm child 19359 (gen 0/slot 7) started
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.160967 2017] [core:trace4] [pid 16941] mpm_common.c(530): mpm child 19360 (gen 0/slot 8) started
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.161421 2017] [core:trace4] [pid 16941] mpm_common.c(530): mpm child 19361 (gen 0/slot 9) started
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.161877 2017] [core:trace4] [pid 16941] mpm_common.c(530): mpm child 19362 (gen 0/slot 10) started
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.162345 2017] [core:trace4] [pid 16941] mpm_common.c(530): mpm child 19363 (gen 0/slot 11) started
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.162792 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 19361] mod_wsgi (pid=19361): Python home /opt/anaconda3.
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.162817 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 19361] mod_wsgi (pid=19361): Initializing Python.
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.166761 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 19362] mod_wsgi (pid=19362): Python home /opt/anaconda3.
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.166806 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 19362] mod_wsgi (pid=19362): Initializing Python.
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.170927 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 19360] mod_wsgi (pid=19360): Python home /opt/anaconda3.
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.170967 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 19360] mod_wsgi (pid=19360): Initializing Python.
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.174897 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 19359] mod_wsgi (pid=19359): Python home /opt/anaconda3.
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.174921 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 19359] mod_wsgi (pid=19359): Initializing Python.
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.178746 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 19363] mod_wsgi (pid=19363): Python home /opt/anaconda3.
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.178769 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 19363] mod_wsgi (pid=19363): Initializing Python.
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.182570 2017] [core:notice] [pid 16941] AH00052: child pid 19317 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.182582 2017] [core:trace4] [pid 16941] mpm_common.c(530): mpm child 19317 (gen 0/slot 0) exited
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.182594 2017] [core:notice] [pid 16941] AH00052: child pid 19318 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.182597 2017] [core:trace4] [pid 16941] mpm_common.c(530): mpm child 19318 (gen 0/slot 3) exited
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.182605 2017] [core:notice] [pid 16941] AH00052: child pid 19319 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.182608 2017] [core:trace4] [pid 16941] mpm_common.c(530): mpm child 19319 (gen 0/slot 4) exited
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.182615 2017] [core:notice] [pid 16941] AH00052: child pid 19320 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.182618 2017] [core:trace4] [pid 16941] mpm_common.c(530): mpm child 19320 (gen 0/slot 5) exited
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.182636 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 16941] mod_wsgi (pid=19321): Process 'store-test' has died but server is being stopped, deregister it.
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.182646 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 16941] mod_wsgi (pid=19321): Process 'store-test' has been deregistered and will no longer be monitored.
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.182934 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 19358] mod_wsgi (pid=19358): Python home /opt/anaconda3.
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.182954 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 19358] mod_wsgi (pid=19358): Initializing Python.
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.186756 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 19357] mod_wsgi (pid=19357): Python home /opt/anaconda3.
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.186781 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 19357] mod_wsgi (pid=19357): Initializing Python.
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.190807 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 19356] mod_wsgi (pid=19356): Python home /opt/anaconda3.
[Wed Mar 01 09:31:17.190840 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 19356] mod_wsgi (pid=19356): Initializing Python.
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
Current thread 0x00007f4ad9333780 (most recent call first):
```

Anyone know what I can do to get it working?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use any system package for mod_wsgi if you are wanting to use Anaconda Python. So first step is to uninstall any system mod_wsgi package.

Then use `pip install mod_wsgi` to install `mod_wsgi-express` into your Anaconda Python installation or virtual environment.

Then run:

```
mod_wsgi-express module-config
```

Take the output of that and put it into your Apache configuration file to load mod_wsgi.

Then add to Apache the mod_wsgi configuration for your specific WSGI application.

Show the configuration you are using after doing that if have issues.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have used Anacondas pip to install _mod_wsgi_. I have loaded that _mod_wsgi_ into apache and removed all others from the apache configuration. I cannot do `mod_wsgi-express module-config` since _module-config_ is not a valid command. Valid commands are _install-module, module-location, setup-server and start-server_. None of which creates an output for use with apache. If I use _start-server_ I can read the apache configuration it uses but it doesn't help my problem. The configuration it uses also requires me to set `PYTHONHOME`.

Comment: You must have done a pip install of mod_wsgi a long time ago and have an old version. Do a ``pip uninstall mod_wsgi`` and then reinstall it.

Comment: I have tried that to without any result. But obliviously something is very wrong. I tried to install anaconda in a fresh ubuntu installation and it works fine there. It was my colleague that installed anaconda on the faulty installation and he might have broken it somehow. Thank you!

Comment: Just for others struggling with getting this to work: when explicitly loading a wsgi module using `LoadModule` in the apache config file, make sure to first disable any previous module managed by apache command line interface, i.e. `a2dismod wsgi` (if you can't / don't want to uninstall it entirely).